# How is it that the following is reduced on the left hand side to d/dx(x^-2y)?

Tags: derivatives

How is it that the following is reduced to $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{-2}y)$ on the left hand side?

Is this an intermediary step?  $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{-2}y - 2x^{-3}y)$

$$ x^{-2}\frac{dy}{dx} -2x^{-3}y = \cos x$$

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{-2}y \right) = \cos x$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the product rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(uv)=u\frac{dv}{dx}+\frac{du}{dx}v
$$
Applied to $u=x^{-2}, v=y$.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply observation regarding product rule. We have d(xy)=xdy+ ydx.
So wherever you see a form xdy+ydx you can write it as d(xy). $\int (xdy+ydx)$ reduces to xy using same thing. So in this example if you observe,you have product of two functions$ x^{-2}$ and$ y$ in the same form ,so it can be reduced to $d(x^{-2}y)$